Question about the degree of a map
Let $ f: S^1 \to S^1 $ be a continuous function. If $[w] \cong 1$ generator of $\pi_1(S^1) \cong\mathbb{Z}$, $\Rightarrow$ $\deg f =  (\xi \circ f_*)([w]) $, where $ \xi: \pi_1(S^1) \to \mathbb{Z} $ is a lift.
Here, the function $ f_*: \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ is defined as $ f_*([w]) = \deg f \cdot [w] $.
In the proof, we have $\xi(f_*([w])) = \deg f \cdot \xi([w]) = \deg f \cdot 1 = \deg f$.
I don't understand the $1$.

You should probably be more precise about what you mean by "don't understand". 1 is an element of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and is a generator of the group.

Reread your second sentence.

Does the proof rely on the fact that if I lift the loop through the lift function, I obtain the generator?

What do you mean by "lift"? What does $\xi$ lift?

It is the lifting correspondence delivered from a covering map

Then $\xi$ is an isomorphism of groups, in particular it's the isomorphism you're using to identify $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so the identity $\xi([w]) = 1$ is by definition. If any of this is unclear or unfamiliar to you I recommend revisiting the calculation of $\pi_1(S^1)$.

The statement you have written is purely algebraic. There is no topology involved. If $\xi:G \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism of groups and $g\in G$ has $\xi(g) = 1$, then $g$ is a generator of $G$. For any $g'\in G$, one has $g' = \xi(g')\cdot g$. So
$$
f_*(g')  = \xi(f_*(g'))\cdot g = \xi(f_*(\xi(g')\cdot g))\cdot g = \xi(g')\cdot \xi(f_*(g))\cdot g
$$
i.e., the map $f_*$ is given by $\xi(g')\cdot g \mapsto \xi(f_*(g)) \cdot (\xi(g')\cdot g)$. Put another way, the map $f_*$ is multiplication by $\deg(f) := \xi(f_*(g))$. This is standard, and seems to be the content of the result you're stuck on.
What is decidedly not standard is defining the specific homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(S^1,p) \to \pi_1(S^1,p)$ for a continuous basepoint-preserving $f:(S^1,p)\to (S^1,p)$ by $f_* = [\ell] \mapsto \deg(f)\cdot[\ell]$. The standard definition for this map is $[\ell] \mapsto [f\circ \ell]$.
Under this standard definition, you have learned something nontrivial from this simple algebra and the somewhat hard-won algebraic topology result that $\pi_1(S^1,p)\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Namely: $f\circ\ell \simeq \deg(f)\cdot\ell$ for any loop $\ell$ where $\deg(f) = \xi([f\circ \ell_0])$ where $\ell_0$ has $\xi([\ell_0]) = 1$. The action of $f$ by composition is, up to homotopy equivalence, the same as concatenation of loops a fixed number of times only depending on $f$.
The wording of your question, the apparent simplicity of the result (it's practically a definition as you've written it), and this non-standard definition of $f_*$ make me feel somewhat concerned that you've abbreviated part of a textbook incorrectly in writing this question. In what I recall of Hatcher's development, one does not define degree this way. Rather, one defines degree in a more general way via homology theory and then perhaps proves that this definition coincides with the one given here.
